# Mongoose find all items with _id from an array that do exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i know that i can search in mongoose like

```
schema.find( { '_id' : { $in: [1,2,3]} }, function(err,data){});
```

my problem is that e.g. objects with _id 1 and 3 exist but no object with _id 2. So the find method will fail. Is there a way to find all possible objects ignoring the inavlid id_s?

Comment: schema.find( { '_id' : { $in: [ObjectId(1),ObjectId(2),ObjectId(3)]} }, function(err,data){});

Comment: The `$in` operator is basically a shortened "OR" condition. So all this really says is *"find all documents where _id is 'either' of these values"*. If it's not there then it's not selected. There is no "fail" here. Unless of course you actually "want" to return no results if not all the listed values are present. Which is different logic to how your question comes across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/), your query should not fail where no documents exist with an id of 2.

The documentation states:

> The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field
>   equals any value in the specified array.

Comment: Correct, the problem was thatone object id could not be parsed.

Comment: Correct, the problem was thatone object id could not be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo first checks the length of _id and it must be 24 characters,

if one of the array members be less than 24 chars it will shows length error to you, for example:

234324533423423423423424 _id is not exists in db

```
 db.users.find({ '_id' :{ $in:[ObjectId("56d461517a2f02941bfb967a"),ObjectId("56d461517a2f02941bfb967e"),ObjectId("234324533423423423423424")]}}, function(err,data){})
```

will work perfectly to show first 2 members!